# A Summation Challenge

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, contest-math

I am trying to understand the solution of   [problem](https://www.codechef.com/DEC12/problems/QPOLYSUM) from its [editorial](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/4505/qpolysum-editorial?sort=votes) by djdolls' answer,I am not able to understand a particulare step which is as follows:
$$S(n)=\sum_0^D (-1)^i \cdot \binom{D+1}{i+1} \cdot S(n -i - 1) \cdot Q^{i + 1}  +   \sum_0^D (-1)^i \cdot \binom{D+1}{i} * S(D - i) \cdot Q^i
$$
The solution says, expand $S(n - i)’s$ until, we have an expression entirely in terms of $S(0), S(1), \ldots , S(D)$.
And the next equation for $S(n)$ author writes is:
$$S(n)=\sum_0^D (-1)^i \cdot \binom{n - D - 1 + i}{i} \cdot \binom{n}{D-i}\cdot S(D-i) \cdot  Q^{n - D + i}  +  \sum_{i=0}^{n-D-1}\binom{D+i}{D} \cdot Q^i
$$
I tried working it out but did not find myself leading to the form above, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do take Q=1,for sake of simplicity...